# Typescript doesn't check for property initialization when merging interface and class

Tags: typescript

If I declare a class like this:

```
class Dog {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}
```

TSC will complain that a, b, and c are not initialized. However, if I do this:

```
interface Animal {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
    c: string;
}

class Dog {
    constructor() {}
}
```

it doesn't care whether the properties are initialized or not. I expected that the compiler would warn me that the properties in the merged interface weren't initialized like the one in the first snippet. What's the logic behind why that's not the case?

Comment: [Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) like that is intended to describe external augmentation of an existing class, not to check the class body itself... if you want that to be checked presumably you would write `class Dog extends Animal` (or `implements Animal`) and then initialize properties in the class itself.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: A class can't extend a type. I could do implements instead, but I didn't want to reuse the properties.

Comment: Sure, if `Animal` is not a superclass then you can't extend it.  What do you mean by "reuse" the properties?  As asked, the question wants to know why declaration merging doesn't require class property initialization, now how to work around it, so... would you accept an answer saying something like "`--strictPropertyInitialization` is not intended to warn about anything that might be externally merged (presumably those properties would be externally initialized also)" along with links to sources?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess the problem was that I was expecting the compiler to warn me that the properties in the merged interface weren't initialized like the one in the first snippet. Would --strictPropertyInitialization solve this?

Comment: Can not reproduce the first example you have. Class declaration with properties should not be a problem in ts. There is a missing part somehow to reproduce your first example error.

Comment: "Would --strictPropertyInitialization solve this" no, that's the only reason you're getting warnings in your first snippet. There is no way to "solve" this using declaration merging.  But your question isn't about solutions, it's a "why" question.  If you need alternative approaches, then this is probably an XY Problem where you were trying to use declaration merging to solve your underlying use case.  If so, then maybe [edit] the question to specifically ask about the use case and not focus on a failed attempt to address it.  What should we do, specifically, to proceed with the question?

Comment: @MehyarSawas [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwFgAoZM5OALmQGcwpQBzAbhPOQCNq6GQWSAviRKhIsRCgAiAe0bIIAD0ggAJjTQZseIqXIJu9Jq2JDiJBDjg11MuTvYJpIHgFcEYaVAAUASgKmBIA) No errors. By the way --strictPropertyInitialization is set

Comment: @jcalz I have edited the question for clarity

Comment: Let's back up; you are already using `--strictPropertyInitialization`, since if you weren't, you wouldn't expect any errors for uninitialized properties, even in your first snippet.  The answer to your question, as asked, is "declaration merging is not meant for this use case, as externally merged properties are generally expected to be externally initialized also."  Do you agree that this fully addresses your question?  Or is there still something missing?

Comment: Yes, that satisfies the problem and I would be happy to accept that as the answer.

Comment: To add on to that, I know I could use implements, but I just wanted to avoid duplicating the field from the interface to the class while also keeping the type checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interpreting the question as:

Why does [merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) an [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) declaration into the instance side of a [`class`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) declaration not cause the compiler to warn when the interface-declared properties are not initialized in the class, even when [the `--strictPropertyInitialization` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#--strictpropertyinitialization) is enabled?"

And the answer is:

The use case for [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) into a class is to patch an existing class from the outside.  Generally speaking, if you augment the class inferface with a new property or method from the outside, you will also initialize the property or method from the outside.  So you'd start with the original class declaration:

```
class Dog {
    constructor() { }
}
```

And then externally you augment the interface and also implement the added properties:

```
interface Animal {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}
interface Dog extends Animal {
    c: string;
}

// implementation
Dog.prototype.a = "defaultA";
Dog.prototype.b = "defaultB";
Dog.prototype.c = "defaultC";
```

If you do that, it will work as expected:

```
const d = new Dog();
console.log(d.b); // "defaultB"
d.b = "newB";
console.log(d.b); // "newB"
```

Meanwhile, the use case for the `--strictPropertyInitialization` compiler option is to verify that the properties declared in the class itself are properly initialized.  This is a separate use case from declaration merging; any properties you need to definitely initialize in the class body should also be declared in the class body.

---

So that's the answer to the question as asked.  It seems you have an underlying need to create a class constructor from an interface without re-declaring the properties in the class, and your attempt to do this was with declaration merging... which is, unfortunately, not the right tool for the job (at least as of TypeScript 4.9).

There are other approaches; sometimes I use what I call an "assigning constructor" factory which only needs to be implemented once:

```
function AssignCtor<T extends object>(): new (init: T) => T {
    return class { constructor(init: any) { Object.assign(this, init); } } as any;
```

and then you can use it to generate class constructors:

```
interface IDog {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}
class Dog extends AssignCtor<IDog>() {
    bark() {
        console.log("I SAY " + this.a + " " + this.b + " " + this.c + "!")
    }
};

const d = new Dog({ a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" });
d.bark(); // I SAY a b c!
```

This may or may not meet your needs, and it's out of scope for the question as asked in any case.  My point is just that you will probably want to look somewhere other than declaration merging to scratch this particular itch.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQ18ZXSCwBQIAEB5ASgSQOIYHIEEAZJAYUPwGUKkAxDQgUQQGMAbAQwGdOkARAewDmSAN4IAkM34A7TgBcATgFdmc-goAUASlFIAvggPwECGGfMXTwJAwAaAFQZoCxfAFUsAWQa57+exgouCaI1gCW0nIApgoAZuzMUQgR0XEJUUj40mEAtuysohLsAFxI8goRggDcEgBGpeWVNfBGyCkx8YlIOTGCSfDtaV0CwlEAHtHSACY8Wbn5hfCSDYpNhlZIuQAOrFE9kexyYTIIIwB0Wwr8anIAnltRZ+xIALxIAERTUfFKrHL472a50u12u90etVeHy+Pz+ACFAachBcrjdwWdmFDPt92L85CREcYiRYSaTwBtHBQArgsCEpLI5EgplDpFEAO58ITaZr0zj8XZnVhcqZnWpaKpIZDY2FyBEIEWQt7vVlshE8mR8gVCwQaBXiyXWZXsuVE6TsHqcLbpTJ-GJm6KLELiWJKaSqY7STLcMKCaQkNQKAA89iQ40mMyQ-FqACsoqoAHzaUoqpAaCJhOSlew6F7xpAhsRLcQKKJyJQKT1sLg8ERIXmKFQBtPZTNIdjSW46WsoGNxuRPb2+jRyAAWYU4ABpNi39Xp9G2eO3bs1xEYJINOhkMCNFuJxCUyqtpNUJOJ6oeKseV8sL2slkZJBxuJzRhMotNZoO-QHA9uhImu1PWp2AUABrbRdz3Xl+UebUNHeDAkAofAAE0PiQABqJBR3HJ5MPQ958JwzhRXwwjCKw4iMTIgBCd4tFPB89GaCR6yZFl2RfDRawPd52HeKdz3eWoBLrUp3mYQi9HFCQFRA8D9WQRDkLQ55IWYGiQkMIA)

Answer (score 0):

As jcalz has mentioned, TypeScript currently does not check for initialized properties with merged declarations. Thus currently, the only way to ensure that the properties are initialized would be to declare them directly within the class like this:

```
class Dog implements Animal {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;

    constructor() {
        this.a = 'a'
        this.b = 'b'
        this.c = 'c'
    }
}
```

However, I still don't think this is the ideal solution and I have submitted an issue about this on the TypeScript repo. You can see it here:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52279